# String class replace() method

Tags: java, string, immutability

How many Object are created in this code snippet?

```
String x = "xyz"; // #1
x.toUpperCase(); /* Line 2 */ #2
String y = x.replace('Y', 'y'); //Will here new object is created or not?
y = y + "abc"; // #3 ?
System.out.println(y);
```

Three. I think..?

Comment: ...what about line 3?

Comment: Add the language tag to your question. Java?

Comment: If this is Java, Strings are immutable so another object will be created in the replace line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many objects are created ?

```
// "xyz" is interned , JVM will create this object and keep it in String pool
String x = "xyz";
// a new String object is created here , x still refers to "xyz" 
x.toUpperCase(); 
// since char literal `Y` is not present in String referenced by x ,
// it returns the same instance referenced by x 
String y = x.replace('Y', 'y'); 
//  "abc" was interned and y+"abc" is a new object
y = y + "abc";  
System.out.println(y);
```

This statement returns a reference to  the same String object `x`:

```
String y = x.replace('Y', 'y');
```

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,char%29):

> **If the character oldChar does not occur in the character sequence represented by this String object, then a reference to this String object is returned.** Otherwise, a new String object is created that represents a character sequence identical to the character sequence represented by this String object, except that every occurrence of oldChar is replaced by an occurrence of newChar.